# What should be displayed when the user selects an overall category?

Tags: buttons, design, filter

**Background**

So I am working on a project for a client that has filters for different weather events. There are categories and sub categories (example below)

- Winter

  - Snow
  - Freezing Rain
  - Sleet
  - Slush

Currently, the user can type a specific event ("Snow") to just get that event. (see below)

[image: Subcategory selected]

Or the category name ("Winter"), and get all of the sub categories to be displayed. (see below)

[image: subcategories]

**Question**

What should be displayed to the user in the filter pane when the category is selected? Should it be the category or all the sub categories?

*Category displays*

[image: Winter]

*Subcategories display*

[image: subcategories]

My thought would be subcategories so if the user wants all but one, they can select the category and then filter down from there, but I'm not sure if that is the best way to go about it.

Comment: This seems like it would depend a lot on the implementation. It'd be really helpful if you could put together a quick wireframe of the current set up, or of your suggested fix (i.e. showing subcategories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could display both if the user typed the main category and dispaly sub-catgories if the user started with a subcategory:

**Winter > Display: Winter, Snow, Freezing Rain,Sleet,Slush**

**Freezing Rain> Display: Sleet,Slush, Snow**

It is also helpful to visually indicate structure when user are selecting, perhaps using a variation of colour to indicate Main category and sub-categories.

I think this is a more flexible approach and gives users more control.